# how to pull the child id from a segment

Tags: categories, solspace-calendar, low-seg2cat, child-categories

I have a single entry page that has a child category selected only (not the parent just the child selected)

I have a Solspace Calendar event entry which has the same child category selected.

Is there a way to display the calendar events with the same child category selected on the single entry page?

**Single entry page template: domain.com/candidate/url-title**

```
{embed="events/candidates_events" calendar_id="{calendar_id}"}
```

**Embed Template:**

```
{exp:calendar:cal 
   calendar_id="{embed:calendar_id}" 
   event_limit="{embed:event_limit}" 
   date_range_start="today" 
   show_months="24" 
   status="not Closed|Private" 
   pad_short_weeks="n" 
   dynamic="on" 
   transcribe="disable"
}
   <li>
       <a href="{exp:transcribe:uri  path='events'}/{event_id}/">
           <strong>{event_title}
       </a>
       ({event_start_date format="%F %j, %Y"})
       </strong>
       <br />
       {event_summary} - 
       <a href="{exp:transcribe:uri  path='events'}/{event_id}/">
            Learn More
       </a>
       <br />
       <br />
    </li>
    {if no_results}
    {/if}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with Solspace Calendar, but it seems version 1 (which I guess you must be using, as the `calendar:cal` tag was dropped for version 2 and beyond) supports use of the parameter `category=`.  So presumably you can grab the ID of the child category you are using and pass that value to your `calendar:cal` tag.

Also, there is a typo in your code - I think your parameter `dynamic="on"` is really meant to be `dynamic="no"`.

HTH